# Link gone missing using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

Below the second picture there was a link before but now it mysteriously has gone missing
http://rosepetals.se.temp-url.se/ Can you see what is wrong?

I got a suggestion below and I have seen it the link is hidden under the picture. How do I move the link down?

I really want the picture to have the position as in the test site..

I edited this question to remove the link to my public sight, as this kind of links were suggested to be avoided by Bartdude

```
     <nav class="navigation">
                 <div class="links">
                     <a href="http://www.student.bth.se/~asfo13/htmlphp/projectBMO/home.php">
                       <img class="krans" src=parlkrans_handslag.jpg alt="Image on pärlkrans">
                     </a>
                    <a href=http://www.student.bth.se/~asfo13/htmlphp/projectBMO/home.php>Begravningsmuseum Online</a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="links">
                     <a href="http://www.student.bth.se/~asfo13/oophp/MovieProject/Embla/webroot/home.php?p=home">
                       <img class="woods" src="woods.jpg" alt="Image from the woods">
                     </a>
                     <a href='http://www.student.bth.se/~asfo13/oophp/MovieProject/Embla/webroot/home.php?p=home'>Movieproject</a>
                 </div>
            </nav>


        .links {

          float:left;
          margin-left:10px;
          margin-right:10px;
          padding-left:10px;
          padding-right:10px;
          margin-bottom: 14px;
          background-color: #ffffff;
          width:260px; 
        }
        .krans{

            width: 160px;
            margin-left:10px;
            margin-right:10px;
            padding-left:10px;
            padding-right:10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .woods{

            width: 314px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 250px;
            margin-left:10px;

        }

    .woods{
        width: 314px;
        /*position: absolute;*/
        left: 250px;
        /*margin-left:10px;*/
        margin-right:10px;
        /*padding-left:10px;*/
        padding-right:10px;

    }

.woods{
    width: 314px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    left: 250px;
    /*margin-left:10px;*/
    margin-right:10px;
    /*padding-left:10px;*/
    padding-right:10px;

}
```

Comment: There is nothing like `www.rosepetals.se` in your code? How it gets missing?

Comment: And this is the answer ^^

Comment: Please don't post live links as it will make your question obsolete as soon it is answered and it's not the goal of SO. A simple inspection with any browser developer tool will show you where your link actually is (hidden under your image). Basically your problem is very bad HTML+CSS structure, so you better fix the whole thing cause else you'll be having a lot of other issues in the future. And this is without even mentionning browser differences...

Comment: You're missing `"` for `href` attributes...

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan: Yes I have, look above at the edited question.

Comment: @Bartdude: The link is under the picture just as you said, what do you mean with very bad HTML CSS structure?

Comment: well although it looked almost ok, you could see that a lot of content was actually displayed outside of the boundaries of their containing block, that blocks were actually a bit overlapping and all this was fixed with "clever" paddings, margins or absolute positionning. In other words, that's the kind of HTML & CSS that's hard to debug cause when you change 1 thing it can have a big impact because of chain reaction, and the rendering on different browsers might be very different too.

Comment: Well I tried different browsers and they showed the same result. But I will continue this evening

Comment: I tried Firefox, Chrome and Opera and they all show the same. On the mobile Chrome on my Xperia V the page is not as perfect yet.

Comment: I solved it but I can not publish it cause of a time limit of 8 hours for new accounts. But I will present it this evening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://rosepetals.se.temp-url.se/
 I solved it using absolute positioning on the link in the CSS class woodslink

```
.woodslink{
    position: absolute;
    left: 370px;
    top: 350px;

}
.links {
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:10px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width:260px; 
}

<div class="links">
                 <a href="http://www.student.bth.se/~asfo13/oophp/MovieProject/Embla/webroot/home.php?p=home"><img class="woods" src="woods.jpg" alt="Image from the woods"></a>
                 <a class="woodslink" href='http://www.student.bth.se/~asfo13/oophp/MovieProject/Embla/webroot/home.php?p=home'>Movieproject</a>
             </div>
```

Comment: This did work, but it is not an optimal solution I have noticed. This use of absolute positioning is not easy to maintain. I will try to find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

your woods.jpg image has `position: absolute`, so the link is actually under the image itself. Just remove the absolute position and adjust the margins (also remove both `padding-left` and `margin-left` from `.wood` element)

As you can see from the screenshot, the link *Movieproject* (highlighted on the left) is under the photo

---

[image]

Be careful using position absolute: *det är ingen dans på rosor* :)

Comment: .woods{
    width: 314px;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    left: 250px;
    /*margin-left:10px;*/
    margin-right:10px;
    /*padding-left:10px;*/
    padding-right:10px;
  
}
I removed as you suggested but now it don't look right

www.rosepetals.se

I really want the picture to have that position..

Comment: as I wrote above, you can easily adjust with margins: e.g. try giving a negative margin-left to the second `.links` element. Or give it position: relative, then move that element wherever you want with top/left properties

Comment: The link is under the picture maybe I should try margin-top? I tried it. I recently opened this account and do not have image rights yet so I can not show a picture. Not the right choice but I’ll go on trying

Comment: I solved it but I can not publish it cause of a time limit of 8 hours for new accounts. But I will present it this evening

Comment: I tried to vote you up as your reply, led me forward. But I really could not, since you have to have 15 reputation to vote.

Answer (score 0):

please remove below properties from this class. 
    .woods{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    }

hope this will solve your problem. :)